# Developing Entity Framework compatible data model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to develop a data model for c# .net Core application using Entity Framework Code first.

What I basicaly have is a data model bellow.

[image]

There are tables `Dog` and `Person`. They each contain different information. For example I can have different type of dogs. Person can have something specific and that would be not applicable for dogs.

There is 1:1 relation between `Person` and `Item`. The same relation is between `Dog` and `Item`.

In addition to that table `ItemReference` contains child-parent relations between Items. For example there is child - parent relation between dog and person (dog owner - dog or persons may be siblings)

I need to make alphabetical list of dogs and persons (mix them up).In addition I need to be able to get to Details page for each of the following.

Using this feels really stupid as there might be more tables in the future. For Example `Cat` or `Car` and I would need to rework these If statements each time.

```
@foreach (var x in Model.Item.OrderBy(y=>y.ItemName))
{
    if (x.ItenType == "Dog")
    {
        <li><a asp-page="DogDetails" asp-route-id="@x.Item.Dog.Id">@x.ItemName</a></li>
    }
    if (x.ItenType == "Person")
    {
        <li><a asp-page="PersonDetails" asp-route-id="@x.Item.Person.Id">@x.ItemName</a></li>
    }
}
```

**Anyone knows how to make such a data model so it is more intelligent design?**

Any help greatly appreciated

Tables `Dog`, `Person` and `Item` will look like this:

Dog

```
Id  DogName     DogTypeId   DogStatusId ItemId
1   "Alex"      1           1           1
2   "Rex"       2           1           2
```

Person

```
Id  PersonName  PersonStatusId      ItemId
1   "Joe"       1                   3     
2   "Jane"      2                   4
```

Item

```
Id  ObjectName   ItemType
1   "Alex"       "Dog"
2   "Rex"        "Dog"
3   "Joe"        "Person"
4   "Jane"       "Person"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object graph isn't entirely clear. It looks like `Dog` and `Person` are just related to `Item`, but based on your description and brief code sample, it would appear that they're actually *types* of items. If that's the case, you should be employing an inheritance strategy, not composition.

```
public class Item

public class Dog : Item

public class Person : Item
```

By default, EF will handle inheritance with a TPH (table per hierarchy) strategy, which doesn't seem appropriate here. Instead, I think you're going to want TPT (table per type) which can be achieved by using the `Table` attribute on your derived classess:

```
[Table("Dogs")]
public class Dog : Item

[Table("Persons")]
public class Person :
```

What this will do is create three tables, `Dogs`, `Persons`, and `Items`. Any data common to all items, regardless of whether it's a dog or person, will obviously go on your `Item` class and will end up in the `Items` table. Foreign keys will be added on both the `Dogs` and `Persons` table pointing to the `Items` table. When you retrieve a `Dog`, for example, EF will automatically join the corresponding record in `Items` to create a complete `Dog`.

This then gives you some special abilities with your queries. You can generically get all items, regardless of type, with `_context.Items` of course, but you can also potentially have separate `DbSet`s for `Dog` and `Person`, allowing you to query those independently: e.g. `_context.Dogs`. Even without an explicit `DbSet`, you can utilize the generic `Set<TEntity>` method: `_context.Set<Dog>()`. Additionally, you can use `OfType<TEntity>` to filter the `Items` set: `_context.Items.OfType<Dog>()`.

Lastly, even if you just retrieve `Items`, EF still tracks what ultimate type each `Item` is, which means you can do things like pattern matching:

```
if (item is Dog dog)
{
    // `dog` is now a variable in this scope of your `item` downcast to `Dog`
}
```

Or in switch statements:

```
switch (item) 
{
    case Dog dog:
        // do something with `dog`
        break;
    case Person person:
        // do something `person`
        break;
    default:
        // do something with generic items (`item`)
        break;
}
```

**EDIT**

I realized that I only alluded to the following, rather than stating explicitly. Since `Dog` and `Person` are totally different tables in TPT, you can define totally separate relationships there. For example, `Dog` could have a relationship with `DogStatus`, without affecting anything that's going on with `Person`. You can technically still do this even with TPH, but you'd end up with a bunch of nullable foreign keys on the `Items` table and that would just be a mess and also breaks normalization.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris - I didn't even know TPT and TPH are so important. I've done a lot of reading and I think I can solve my problem now.

Comment: I tried to solve my situation using TPT, but no new tables are created for inherited class. There is Item table with column Discriminator - this is basicaly the same thing I already have. I read something about TPT not being supported in EF Core could you confirm this or is there some workaround? Thanks in advance